# ElasticSearch Lucene full text search using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-java-api, booleanquery

I've recently started using ElasticSearch. I've managed to integrate them successfully, but I find the search API rather complex and confusing. The Java API is not too helpful either. How is it possible to search the following JSON for the fieldname `title` with Lucene syntax `AND` and `OR` using java api?

```
{
    "queryId": 2,
    "queryName": "beta",
        "query": {
            "lang": "en",
            "location": "pa",
            "title": "americanlegion OR concernedvets AND conversion"
      }
  }
```

I've tried `boolean query` but they don't feed my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be good if you could show what you tried with the `BoolQuery` and explain why it didn't work. Here is an example of your query using the Java API's `BoolQuery`.

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("lang", "en"));
boolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("location", "en"));

BoolQueryBuilder titleBoolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
titleBoolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("title", new String[]{"americanlegion", "conversion"}));
titleBoolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("title", "conversion"));

boolQuery.should(titleBoolQuery);
```

Resulting JSON:

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "should" : [ {
            "terms" : {
                "lang" : [ "en" ]
            }
        },{
            "terms" : {
                "location" : [ "pa" ]
            }
        },{
            "bool" : {
                "must" : {
                    "term" : {
                         "title" : "conversion"
                    }
                },
                "should" : {
                    "terms" : {
                        "title" : [ "americanlegion", "conversion" ]
                     }
                }
            }
       } ]
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use the Lucene syntax use the `QueryStringQueryBuilder`

```
QueryStringQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.queryString("user.name:\"John\" OR user.name:\"Matt\"");
```

this will produce the JSON

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "query" : "user.name:\"John\" OR user.name:\"Matt\""
    }
}
```

Comment: The user enters a Lucene query. for example: John OR Matt and the JSON looks like:
"LQuery":{"query":"user.name:\\\"John\\\" OR user.name:\\\"Matt\\\""}
How can this be queried using ES java api?

Comment: See my edit for how to use the Lucene syntax with the Java API.